# creating a jar-with-dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I am creating a `jar-with-dependencies` in `mvn 3.0.3`. I have successfully done this in one project (using just `mvn install`) and created a complete jar-wth-dependencies. I copied the relevant chunk of POM code (`<plugins>...</plugins>`, which someone else wrote!) to the current project (which differs in that it has assemblies). It creates the normal snapshot jar (`jumbo-converters-compchem-gaussian-0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar`) but no `jar-with-dependencies`.  How should I amend the POM?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>cml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jumbo-converters</artifactId>
    <version>0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<artifactId>jumbo-converters-compchem-gaussian</artifactId>
<name>jumbo-converters-compchem-gaussian</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${jumbo.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>jumbo</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jumbo-converters-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jumbo-converters-compchem-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jumbo-converters-templates</artifactId>
        <version>0.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jumbo-converters-testutils</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jumbo-converters-compchem-testutils</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>org.xmlcml.cml.converters.compchem.gaussian.GaussianLogXML2CompchemConverter</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>.hgsub</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/.hg/</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/.project</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/external/</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>org.xmlcml.cml.converters.compchem.gaussian.GaussianLogXML2CompchemConverter</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>.hgsub</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/.hg/</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/.project</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/external/</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Have you tried `mvn assembly:single` ?

Comment: No. I will try it (have never used it before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,
Use maven dependency plugin to retrieve/store the dependencies (more info [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html)) to your project folder.
Ex: Say lib folder.

Now mark this lib folder as a "Resources" folder.
Like,

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>lib</directory>
    <targetPath>lib</targetPath>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Now mvn install should include the dependencies in your final artifact.
(copying Shinchan's comment to here so it can be formatted:

> Simple add this to ur pom.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>lib</directory>
            <targetPath>lib</targetPath>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>

                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Simple add this to ur pom.<build>
  <resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>lib</directory>
    <targetPath>lib</targetPath>
   </resource>
  </resources>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <phase>install</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>