# How to copy files from classpath with maven

Tags: maven, copy, classpath, maven-3, maven-dependency-plugin

I need to extract several XML configurations, which are placed in distinct artefacts, but in the same package in classpath. I need to do this, because then i merge them with XSLT transformation.

**I don't want to specify name of each artefact in pom.** The plugin should take whole classpath from all dependencies.

I have found snippet with `maven-dependency-plugin`, which partially do what i need (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-artifacts.html)

But i would like to specify just classpath, no arteract such as:

```
 <configuration>
   <artifactItems>
     something like ALL
   </artifactItems>
   <includes>my/xml/config/package/*settings.xml</includes>
   <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/tmp</outputDirectory>
     ...
 </configuration>
```

Is it possible? and is `maven-dependency-plugin` the right choise?

**EDIT : MODEL USECASE**

i have 2 jars:

- `a.jar` in which classpath is file `my/xml/config/package/a-settings.xml`
- `b.jar` in which classpath is file `my/xml/config/package/b-settings.xml`

i want to specify only `my/xml/config/package/*settings.xml` and be able to copy files `a-settings.xml` and `b-settings.xml` somwhere without specifiing, that they are in jars `a.jar` and `b.jar` (only that they are in dependencies classpath)

Because it is possible, that in the future i will need to add `c.jar` with `c-settings.xml` and so on..

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16918467/1352127) to copy your dependencies to some empty directories. And then like you have mentioned above, include the necessary xmls in some other output directory.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Answer you are refering to doesn't really show how to copy some files from classpath despite jar file they are placed in.. I added model usecase to my question to make myself clear. Thanks again

Comment: hmm ... For this usecase, I don't know how to do in maven. But, you can try using maven-antrun-plugin (or some other plugin like groovy scripting plugin) to play with your retrieved jars. Just make sure to use proper lifecycle phase in maven(to invoke the script at proper time e.g. like before compilation phase).